# Redefining an unloaded class with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to redefine an unloaded class and get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class already loaded. The code is taken straight from the tutorial, only had to append "getLoaded()" for it to compile, see below. ByteBuddy version is the latest available 1.12.10, Java version 1.8.0_202. I tried a few other JVMs too getting same results.

I see that ByteArrayClassLoader is loading the class using Launcher$AppClassLoader instead of self. This causes the exception.

What do I need to make it work?

Thank you

```
class MyApplication  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TypePool typePool = TypePool.Default.ofSystemLoader();
        Class bar = new ByteBuddy()
          .redefine(typePool.describe("foo.Bar").resolve(), // do not use 'Bar.class'
                    ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.ofSystemLoader())
          .defineField("qux", String.class) // we learn more about defining fields later
          .make()
          .load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()) .getLoaded();
        assertThat(bar.getDeclaredField("qux"), notNullValue());
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class already loaded: class foo.Bar
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader.load(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:362)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$WrappingDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:367)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:148)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:101)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:6166)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:6154)
    at MyApplication.main(UnloadedTest.java:17)
```

Comment: The JVM has no concept of unloading classes. What makes you assume you managed to unload it? Or do you simply mean that the class was not loaded yet? Either way, your assumption seems to be wrong. Obviously, despite your contrary expectation, it was loaded already.

Comment: @kriegaex my interpretation is the OP means “not yet loaded” and the posted code has been invoked with `MyApplication` as main class, so no other code than shown (which only consists of calls into ByteBuddy) should be executed. So the question is, what did load the `foo.Bar` class.

Comment: Yes, @Holger is right. I meant a class that is not loaded yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a default class loading strategy which is one without use of Unsafe, but one that is creating a new class loader as a child of the supplied loader. This new loader will query its parent - the system class loader - first, which then loads `Foo`. After `Foo` is defined, it cannot be defined once again in the new child.

You can avoid this by injecting the class using an injection-based strategy like `ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION` or a lookup-based one (`ClassLoadingStrategy.UsingLookup`). This way, no child loader is created but the altered class is injected into the system loader. Or you can disable querying the child loader by using `ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.CHILD_FIRST` where any regular reference to `Foo` in the reminder of the program will however load the original class in addition.

Comment: Rafael, you probably wanted to write "you can disable querying the **parent** loader"?

Comment: Yes! It works for me with .load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION) and with .load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.CHILD_FIRST). It appears that lookups are not for Java 8 but the first two options are good there. Thank you very much!